# MongoDB Dot-Notation Query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB and I'm having trouble with getting my dot-notation queries to work...

I am using pymongo with MongoDB running on a remote Amazon EC2 instance...

Instead of writing massive XML parsing code to extract lots of different data, I am converting the XML to JSON, dumping everything into MongoDB, and then attempting to extract the pieces of data I want using dot-notation queries...

The data gets converted into JSON and inserted into Mongo fine.  I can see all of the inserts (from the python shell)...

for item in db.feed.find():
    item

Here is an example item that is returned...

```
   {u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 8, 20, 19, 55, 87000), u'message': u'{"category": {"text": "Scores"}, "XML_File_ID": {"text": "12292403"}, "game": {"status": {"text": "4 Qtr", "attrib": {"numeral": "4", "type": "P"}}, "time_r": {"text": "10:01"}, "vscore": {"text": "27"}, "vteam": {"text": "Pittsburgh", "attrib": {"id": "082"}}, "hteam": {"text": "Cincinnati", "attrib": {"id": "064"}}, "hscore": {"text": "14"}}, "seasontype": {"text": "Regular"}, "schedule_id": {"text": "3151"}, "location": {"city": {"text": "Pittsburgh"}, "state": {"text": "PA"}, "country": {"text": "USA"}}, "time_stamp": {"text": " November 8, 2010, at 11:19 PM ET "}, "game_id": {"text": "3151"}, "sport": {"text": "NFL"}, "heading": {"text": "BC-ABP+082:064* 27 14 4R10:01"}}', u'_id': ObjectId('4cd8cbebe8b5d58527000016')}
```

So I'm trying to do a query like this, but I'm not getting any results...

db.feed.find_one({"message.category.text": "Scores"})

What's the proper way to do these type of queries and get the whole document back in the response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested those queries, both from within the MongoDB shell and using pymongo and they work for me. Are you forgetting to save the results to a variable and/or print them?

Comment: Thanks Charles, I found the main problem, just pilot error.  When inserting the message data (converted from xml to json), double-quote characters are left around the json "message" object, rendering it as plain text instead of a json object. On the python side I just do an eval(jsonString) to get rid of the double-quotes that get inserted...

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that my dot-notation queries had to be fully-qualified from the top of the document.  For example, I was hoping to search for {"game_id.text": "3151"}, but I need to search from the top of the json document with {"message.game.game_id.text": "3151"}

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into $elemmatch if you are deailing with queries on subdocment queries a lot.

*"Using the $elemMatch query operator (mongod >= 1.3.1), you can match an entire document within an array."*

More here: [official docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-Matchingwith%24elemMatch) & a [blog post](http://learnmongo.com/posts/reaching-inside-with-dot-notation-and-elemmatch/) ...

Answer (score 0):

your inserted json object has (u'). This is the problem, XML to JSON conversion is incorrect.

```
 u'message:u'{category:{text:"scores"}
```